# Boost 1.71 Получить io_context из basic_socket

Tags: c++, boost

Вопрос по модулю boost::asio, версия boost 1.71. Кто-нибудь подскажет, можно ли каким-то образом получить используемый io_context из объекта basic_socket? Необходимость возникла при преходе с boost 1.62, там это делалось просто с помощью метода basic_socket::get_io_service(). А сейчас совсем непонятно как его получить..

Я пробовал, как рекомендует сам boost:

```
// сокет socket
asio::executor e = socket.get_executor();
asio::execution_context &e_context = e.context();
```

Затем:

```
asio::io_context &context_instance = static_cast<asio::io_context&>(e_context);
```

Но это выглядит опасно, хотя работает.

Comment: на замену был добавлен метод get_executor

Comment: Имеется в виду base_socket::get_executor() или io_context::get_executor()?